# wordpress menu adding unpredictable items

Tags: wordpress, menu

Wordpress menu is adding several additiom and empty a tags (exacly two)[image]

```
if (has_nav_menu('secondary')) :
    ?>
    <nav id="menu-secondary-title" class="nav-anchors">
        <div class="wrap">
            <a id="menu-secondary-anchor" class="menu-secondary-anchor" title="<?php _e('Secondary Mobile Menu', 'path'); ?>" href="#menu-secondary-mobile"><?php //_e( 'Check Us Out!', 'path' );  ?></a>
            <div id="mobile-menu-secondary">
                <a href="#"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/Hamburger_icon.svg.png"</a>
                <?php wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location' => 'secondary', 'container_class' => 'menu-secondary-mobile-top', 'menu_class' => '', 'menu_id' => 'menu-secondary-items', 'fallback_cb' => '')); ?>
            </div>

        </div><!-- .wrap -->

    </nav><!-- #menu-secondary-title -->

    <nav id="menu-secondary" class="menu-container">
        <div class="wrap clr">
            <?php wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location' => 'secondary', 'container_class' => 'menu', 'menu_class' => '', 'menu_id' => 'menu-secondary-items', 'fallback_cb' => '')); ?>
        </div><!-- .wrap -->
    </nav><!-- #menu-secondary .menu-container -->

<?php endif; ?>
```

Please, help me find where could be something wrong. Which which next wordpress file can I explore, to find where is problem?

Comment: Your title is confusing

Comment: Sorry, I corrected it.

Comment: Its coming from this  <?php wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location' => 'secondary', 'container_class' => 'menu-secondary-mobile-top', 'menu_class' => '', 'menu_id' => 'menu-secondary-items', 'fallback_cb' => '')); ?>

Comment: Your `img` tag is not closed out correctly. I don't think that would be related, but try fixing that and see what happens. `<a href="#"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/Hamburger_icon.svg.png" /></a>`